# Read file under web-inf from non-servlet class

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I have to store some sql files under webapp and read queries as required. I have placed them under `WEB-INF/sqlQueries`.

I want to read these file from a non-servlet class. I am able to read them from servlet class by `context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/sqlQueries/" + fileName + ".sql")`

Essentially it would be like,

```
WEB-INF
  |
  sqlQueries
     |
     query1.sql
  |
  classes
     |
     com
      |
      appName
        |
        util
        |
        ReadFile.java
```

I need to read these files from com/appname/util/FileReader. How to resolve absolute/relative path here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

> The `"/"` represents the web content root

Then append path to file whichever you want

Comment: That is one option. Is it possible to do without passing servletcontext object?